# How to run python script with Laravel's command fire method?

Tags: php, python, laravel, console, command

I have a need to execute a Python script from a Laravel Command, but I can't find any methods in `Illuminate\Console\Command` to complete my task.

I want to run this command via the console:

```
C:\Python34\python H:\myapp\app\python\questionPopulator.py
```

To do so, I tried the following in my commands `fire()` method:

```
public function fire()
{
    $this->call('C:\Python34\python H:\myapp\app\python\questionPopulator.py');
}


public function fire()
{
    $this->line('C:\Python34\python H:\myapp\app\python\questionPopulator.py');
}
```

None of them work, as Laravel is expecting me to be calling another Laravel command from them. What is the best way to call a simple python script via a Laravel Command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try PHP exec function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
exec('C:\Python34\python H:\myapp\app\python\questionPopulator.py');
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you got a few options

1) system

```
  system('C:\Python34\python H:\myapp\app\python\questionPopulator.py');
```

2) exec

```
  exec('C:\Python34\python H:\myapp\app\python\questionPopulator.py');
```

3) shell_exec - my favorite

```
  $result = shell_exec('C:\Python34\python H:\myapp\app\python\questionPopulator.py');
```

shell_exec runs the script but returns a string.

You could encode the result in a json format.

This way the 2 ecosystems are kept separately.